# Using listbox to display 2 columns from an excel file

Tags: excel, vb.net, webforms

I have to display an excel sheet on a ListBox in VB.net. So far I have been able to display the first column. I have used zones to format two columns. Here is my code for this part:

```vb
Dim fmtStr As String = "{0,15}, {1,15}"
```

I then have this code for displaying in the ListBox:

```vb
For i = 0 To AscW(ListBox1.Items.Count.ToString()(i = i + 1)) - 1

cella = "A" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)
cellb = "B" & Convert.ToString(i + 1)

cella = aSheet.Range(cella).Value
cellb = aSheet.Range(cellb).Value
ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format(fmtStr, "1", "2"))
If cella = "" Or cellb = "" Then
    ListBox1.Items.Add("")
Else
    ListBox1.Items.Add(String.Format(fmtStr, cella, cellb))
End If
```

I'm getting errors while running.. Is there another method to display the columns side by side ?

UPDATE: Everything is working fine but the output is messy like so:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aX5Ls.png)

Comment: I am not familiar with the code on the `For` line. What are you trying to do? Is it `For i = 0 To ListBox1.Items.Count - 1` Then you make assignments to `cella` and `cellb`. Then you reassign those two variables on the next 2 lines. Why make the first assignment if they will be overwritten immediately?

Comment: Use the debugger to step through. Separate reading the values and filling them into the list. Find out whether the mistake is made reading the values or filling the list. The `ListBox1.Items.Add(..)` before the `If` certainly looks suspicious to me...

Comment: Your `frmStr` indicates index 0 and index 2. Then `String.Format(fmtStr, "1", "2")` provides inserts for indexes 0 and 1.

Comment: @Mary this is a tutorial I found to which I made some adjustments..

Comment: So everything is working fine now, but the layout of the columns are really messy. Is there a way to tidy it up ?

Comment: @Mary yes i found this mistake in the frmStr, I edited the questions, is the edit visible ?

Comment: Your messy format is due to the variable length of the data in cella.  Options are to either use padding on cella value so that it's a fixed length, although may still be slightly out due to proportional fonts or second option is to save your data to a data table object, then bind that to a GridView (or like) control which supports columns

Comment: How can I use padding in code behind? Is that possible ? @Hursey

Comment: Read up on the String.PadRight and String.PadLeft functions

Comment: Change the font of the listbox to "Consolas".

Comment: Another option is to use tabulators to delimit the left and the right part, but unfortunately that is getting tricky because you don't know how many tabs you are going to need except if you measure the text's going-to-be with using some GDI methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
ListBox1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Consolas", 8.25!, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, CType(0, Byte))
```